# How do you find missing probabilities from a distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am given the following independent joint distributions:

\begin{align*}
P(X=2, Y=0) &= 1/2\\
P(X=2, Y=1) &= 1/4\\
P(X=1, Y=0) &= p\\
P(X=1, Y=1) &= q
\end{align*}

When solving for $p$ and $q$, I have determined that $\frac12 + \frac14 + p + q = 1$. Also, $p + q = \frac14$.

How do we further break this down to find the exact probabilities for $p$ and $q$?

Comment: You don't have enough information.  Do you know anything else about $X$ and $Y$?  For example, are they independent?

Comment: Have edited the question to reflect that they are in fact independent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $p + q = 1/4$.    Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent you have $P(X = 1, Y = 0) = P(X = 1) P(Y = 0)$.  Now $P(X = 1) = p + q = 1/4$ and $P(Y = 0) = 1/2 + p$.  So you get the equation $p = (1/4)(1/2 + p)$, which you can solve for $p$.

Comment: Thank you for the help!